# Cognos Content store - decode objid

Tags: cognos-bi

I want to get a report of all user names and User IDs. I got the User names but see the UserIDs are in encrypted format. Please help me on How to decrypt the objid in the Content store table CMOBJPROPS1 or any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no report you can run or any way that you can do this from within Cognos, sorry about that.

BUT there's this nifty tool which IBM offers as is, and it does probably exactly what you're looking for: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24034217

You can even export the data if you do want to report off it.

PS: Don't report off the Content Store, it's not a good idea. If you did want to see usernames you could look at cmobjprops33 I guess. Just use the tool, it's better all around.